# How to move certain elements from linked list at the end of that list?

Tags: c, linked-list

Today i was trying to make a program that would enter 15 random values (from 100 to 120) into linked list.
That part works like a charm. Then I went to find the max and the min values from that list, and find the average.

I want to **move all values greater than average to the end of that list** which I tried to realise using function prebaci.
Function unos puts all elements into the list, and function unosK puts all elements at the end of the list. Program goes into infinite loop, and I don't know why. Can you help me to move all values greater than average (107) to the end of the list?
My CODE:

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

typedef struct lista* Pozicija;
struct lista {
    int el;
    Pozicija next;
};

void unos(Pozicija P, int el);//input front
void ispis(Pozicija P);//print 
int mini(Pozicija P);//find min
int maxi(Pozicija P);//find max
void prebaci(Pozicija P,int x);//function for transfering at the end
void unosK(Pozicija P,int x);//input end

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    struct lista L;
    L.next = NULL;
    int min,max, i,j;
    int prvi[21], drugi[15];
    int avg;

    
    for (i = 0;i < 21;i++) {
        prvi[i] = i + 100;
        printf("%d ", prvi[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0;i < 15;i++) {
        int temp = prvi[i];
        int random = rand() % 15;

        prvi[i] = prvi[random];
        prvi[random] = temp;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0;i < 15;i++) {
        //printf("%d ",prvi[i]);
        unos(&L, prvi[i]);
    }

    printf("Ispis\n");
    ispis(L.next);

    printf("\n\n");
    min = mini(L.next);
    printf("Minqi:%d\n", min);

    printf("\n\n");
    max = maxi(L.next);
    printf("Miaxi:%d\n", max);

    printf("\n\n");
    avg = (min + max) / 2;
    printf("avg:%d\n", avg);

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Prebacaj:\n");
    prebaci(&L, avg);
    ispis(L.next);

}
void unos(Pozicija P, int el) {
    Pozicija q;
    q = (Pozicija)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));

    q->el = el;
    q->next = P->next;
    P->next = q;
}
void ispis(Pozicija P) {
    while (P != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", P->el);
        P = P->next;
    }
}
int mini(Pozicija P) {
    int min;
    min = INT_MAX;

    while (P != NULL) {
        if (min > P->el) {
            min = P->el;
        }
        P = P->next;
    }
    return min;
}
int maxi(Pozicija P) {
    int max;
    max = INT_MIN;

    while (P != NULL) {
        if (max< P->el) {
            max = P->el;
        }
        P = P->next;
    }
    return max;
}
void prebaci(Pozicija P,int x) {
    P = P->next;
    Pozicija t;
    t = P;
    while (t != NULL) {
        if (t->el > x)
        {
            unosK(P, t->el);
            t = t->next;
        }
        else if (t->el <= x) {
            unos(P, t->el);
            t = t->next;
        }
        
    }

}
void unosK(Pozicija P,int x) {
    Pozicija q=NULL;
    q = (Pozicija)malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    q->el = x;

    while (P->next != NULL)
            P = P->next;

    
    q->next = P->next;
    P->next = q;

}
```

Comment: If you are iterating over a linked list and are repeatedly adding elements to the end of that list, an infinite loop becomes sort of inevitable.

Comment: You are calculating the average of the min and max values rather than the average of the whole list. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Jack Jones Why is there used the number 15 instead of the number 21 in the loop for (i = 0;i < 15;i++) {
        //printf("%d ",prvi[i]);
        unos(&L, prvi[i]);
    } ?

Comment: @Jack Jones It is a bad idea to have a dummy node (the first node) in the list.

Comment: You could avoid the infinite loop by moving the greater than average elements to a new list and then appending the new list to the end of the old list.

Comment: Try printing the list within `prebaci`, after you call `unosK`. `unosK` is creating a new node at the end of the list. What happens to the previous node of value `x` (the node pointed by `t` in `prebaci`)?

Comment: @Abion47 How to escape that infinite loop?

Comment: @IanAbbott I just wanted to calculate the average of the whole list. I thought this is the algorithm to do it. It gives me a good average value (107). 
I know I can do that, but is there any possibility to switch values without needing an additional linked list?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Because I wanted to randomize my numbers. I couldn't make any other algorithm that would randomize my numbers (without duplicates) and enter them into the linked list.
I know it is a bad idea to have a dummy node haha, you've told me that few months ago. They taught us to do it that way at the Uni and I got comfortable with it.

Comment: @zois I tried printing the list within prebaci function but I think that it gave me an infinite loop as well. I don't know what happens to the previous node since it is hard for me too look it up in the debugger (because of the infinite loop). Could you make printing list within the function without infinite loop?

Comment: This problem was stuck with me for hours and now I'm experiencing a burnout. I tried lots of different ways of fixing the problem, but none of them worked. I also couldn't find any similar program here.

Comment: @Jack Jones Another way is to remember the pointer to the first element added to the end of the list, and stop processing the list when you get to that element.

Comment: @IanAbbott It is hard for me to imagine that since I'm only a beginner. Could you write some code as an example of adding values greater than average to the end of the list?

Comment: `prebaci` is calling `unos` and `unosK` to allocate new elements copied from the old elements, but what is it supposed to do with the old elements?

Comment: @JackJones There are several ways to accomplish this. One is to keep track of where the canonical end of the list is so you don't iterate past it. Another as has been suggested is to move items to a separate list and then, once iteration is over, concatenate that list onto the end of the original list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working, drop-in replacement for the original `prebaci` function. It still has the dummy node at the start of the list, but does not allocate any new elements.

Rather than calling `unos` and `unosK` which allocate new elements, it manipulates the pointers in the original list to move the elements greater than the average value to the end of the list.

It first moves the greater than average elements from the original list onto a new, initially empty list (`q`), and then links the last element of the original list to the first element of the new list so that all the greater than average elements are now at the end of the original list.

The new list (`q`) has been implemented as a pointer instead of a dummy node.

The function makes use of pointers to pointers (`pp` and `pq`) to manipulate the links in the original list and the new list.

```
void prebaci(Pozicija P,int x) {
    Pozicija *pp = &P->next; /* pointer to link in original list */
    Pozicija q = NULL; /* new list for elements greater than average */
    Pozicija *pq = &q; /* pointer to end link of new list */
    while (*pp != NULL) {
        if ((*pp)->el > x) {
            /* move element from original list to end of new list */
            *pq = *pp;  /* end of new list points to moved element */
            *pp = (*pp)->next; /* remove element from original list */
            pq = &(*pq)->next; /* update pointer to end link of new list */
        }
        else {
            /* do not move this element */
            pp = &(*pp)->next; /* advance to next link in original list */
        }
    }
    *pq = NULL; /* terminate the new list */
    *pp = q; /* append the new list to the end of the original list */
}
```

Comment: That code makes average value as the fist element. I think you misunderstood me sir. Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it, but I was thinking about making my program to move only greater values at the end of the list. So only values greater than average (107) should be in the list.

Comment: @JackJones The code separates the list into two (unequal) halves such that all the elements less than or equal to the average end up in the first half, and all the elements greater than the average end up in the second half.

Comment: @JackJones For example, with the average set to 107 then the list 100 103 102 113 112 108 114 109 105 106 104 101 111 110 107 will be changed to 100 103 102 105 106 104 101 107 113 112 108 114 109 111 110. Everything greater than 107 has been moved to the end of the list.

Comment: that's it. I haven't thought about that haha, I'm working on plenty other projects so my brain got overworked and I lost concentration. Thank you for your time and help!